# LibPCap & Packet Drops - Linux

Tags: c, sockets, udp, libpcap, centos7

My app uses libpcap to capture UDP packets from various sources. Occasionally the app has to do some heavy computational work (ballpark ~2 seconds)... during this time the app is not 'reading' from libpcap. This is leading to packet drops, but I'm struggling to understand why. The kernel is not dropping the packets & I think the socket buffers should be large enough.

The interface is receiving ~1000 packets per second. The max packet size is ~600 bytes. So let's call it 1MB/s (overestimate).

I've set the libpcap buffer size to 4MiB (passing to libpcap as bytes) and snapshot length to ~600 bytes.

I've also modified some OS params (Centos7):

```
    /proc/sys/net/core/netdev_max_backlog: 10000
    /proc/sys/net/core/optmem_max: 8388608
    /proc/sys/net/core/rmem_default: 8388608
    /proc/sys/net/core/rmem_max: 8388608
```

Result from netstat -i:

```
    Iface  MTU  RX-OK     RX-ERR RX-DRP RX-OVR    
    eno2   1500 558672786 0      0      0
```

I've tried making all of these values even larger but the number of dropped packets doesn't appear to reduce.

Something which might be worth mentioning... I also have tcpdump running on the same box capturing the same UDP packets (the packets are multicast). It does raise from questions re when do packets gets removed from certain buffers (or parts of the stack).

I'm lost here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using pcap so you can sniff traffic geared for some other application (promiscuous mode), or are you using it to read directed traffic?  If you are using it in promiscuous mode, once the other program has read the data, you may no longer see the packet.

Comment: Not using it in promiscuous mode. A separate (third app) subscribes to the multicast group on the interface. The other apps (i.e, my app and tcpdump) are capturing this multicast data. My app processes the data and performs some action, whilst tcpdump just writes the data to a file. Both tcpdump and my app receive the data without a problem - outside of the scenario I mentioned in my original post.

Comment: I assume it isn't always 2 seconds of processing time per packet.  Why not have a reader thread (that uses pcap) and push a copy of the packet into a queue.  Then a second processing thread deals with processing the records?  At your data rate, you can clearly handle the overhead of memory copies.

Comment: Thanks Digger. That is a good suggestion. But I'm still confused about how packets are currently being dropped - what am I missing?